# MySQL query to SELECT rows with LIKE and create new column containing the matched string

Tags: mysql, select, compare, match, sql-like

I need some help with a MySQL query I am struggling for some time now.

So, I am trying to create a MySQL query to `SELECT` rows from a table that match a specific string like `app`.
My table is like this:

```
+-----+--------------+
| id  | name         |
+-----+--------------+
|   1 | Green Apple  |
|   2 | Big Orange   |
|   3 | application  |
+-----+--------------+
```

I can find all rows that contain `app` string with `SELECT` and `LIKE`.

However, I also want to create new column that contains the string from `name` column which matches `app` and keep the database case sensitive format, i.e. with `app` as a match phrase the new column will contain `App` and `app` entires according to the string format in `name`.

My query so far goes like this:

```
SELECT *, 'what_to_put?' as new_column FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%".$app."%'
```

The desired output is the following:

```
+-----+--------------+-------------+
| id  | name         | new_column  |
+-----+--------------+-------------+
|   1 | Green Apple  |     App     |
|   2 | application  |     app     |
+-----+--------------+-------------+
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a separate regex library, you'll need to use the built-in [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html) to find the [location](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) of the match, and then extract the matching [sub-string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring):

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  name, 
  substring(name, locate('app', name), length('app')) as new_column 
FROM yourTable 
WHERE name LIKE '%app%'
```

Which gives the results:

```
+----+-------------+------------+
| id |    name     | new_column |
+----+-------------+------------+
|  1 | Green Apple | App        |
|  3 | application | app        |
+----+-------------+------------+
```

[Sql Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8daf/7)

Comment: Thanks, mate! Great solution, just what I needed!